# info on Drag Entered

Tags: java, android, view, drag-and-drop

When I *drag* my `View`, I want to be able to see what view I am *dragging* into upon *drag entered*.
I know I can get the `View` that I am dragging by using

```
View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
```

Is there a way to get the `View` of the *drag entered* object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no easy way of doing it.
i was able to get the view by going through the views in my layout in a for loop and finding the view by checking equality.